# How to go from C/C++ & Python Game programming into Web Programming?

Tags: javascript

I have been programming in C/C++ for about five years and Python for three; I mainly program in Python though. My main focus has been on Game programming and Network programming (centered on making scalable multi-player servers.) Recently I have been wanting to switch over to web programming; predominately client-side based applications written in javascript. I was looking to find some advice as to where to get started. I would like to know if there are any decent-good materials on learning javascript, mixed with web programming, for a more advanced programmer. My main problem is that there are just so many sources out there that I don't know where to start. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you've probably heard about flash, which can be a pretty consistent game platform, but requires a browser plugin. ActionScript 3 is pretty similar to JavaScript and is actually based on ES4, which is trashed in favor of ES5 (ES == EcmaScript == JavaScript).

To create pure HTML/JS games, canvas based frameworks are your best chance in terms of standards and wide browser support, whilst SVG is actually a better candidate imo. due to interactivity options, but <canvas> is becomming the standard.

3D is possible however very processor intensive so in the end not YET viable, flash for 3D is still a better option.

Below are a few links of JS game engines I googled quickly for, I am sure there are more out there.

[GameJS](http://tommysmind.com/)
[GameQuery](http://gamequery.onaluf.org/)

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, but I was looking more into actual web design.